# jQuery hide or show animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to copy that animation you see on http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/truehost/faq.html

You click on the Plus symbol it shows the content and click it back (minus symbol) it hides the text.

So, this is what I did in my code to copy that behavior:

My about.html

```
<div class="post-content wow fadeInUp"> 
    <ul class="toggle-list">
    <li>
    <h2 class="acc_active">My questions</h2>
    <div class="ac-content">My answer</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My style.css

Copied this code from that template's style.css and added to my style.css

```
.toggle-list {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.toggle-list li {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:solid 3px #ddd
}
.toggle-list li h2 {
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -html-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    color:#555;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:20px;
    font-family:Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serifr;
    padding:7px 20px 0 60px;
    font-weight:700;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    margin:10px 0
}
.toggle-list li .acc_active:hover {
    color:#777;
    background:url(../images/icon-slide-plus.png) 20px center no-repeat;
    padding-left:80px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s
}
.toggle-list .ac-content {
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    border-top:solid 1px #e5e5e5
}
.acc_active {
    background:url(../images/icon-slide-plus.png) 20px center no-repeat;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    height:32px
}
.acc_noactive {
    background:url(../images/icon-slide-min.png) 20px center no-repeat
}
img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto
}
.img-left {
    float:left;
    margin:5px 15px 15px 0
}
.img-right {
    float:right;
    margin:5px 0 15px 15px
}
```

Added the toggle function to my custom.js that you see on the custom.js of that template http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/truehost/js/custom.js

I somehow cannot get the effect to work on my site. It shows the answer straight away and the question is not displayed at all.

How do I copy that effect? Any help please?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: yeah, a fiddle would be helpful. Also just the act of isolating the problem might help you figure it out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gXdMc/729/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `.slideToggle()` by using jQuery.

Example:

```
$( ".toggle-list li h2" ).click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".ac-content" ).slideToggle( );
});
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u2ec3ce2/10/

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

---

Updated to use .siblings() selector since you'll have multiples on the page.

Comment: @BhavaniKannan awesome, glad to hear.

Comment: I think I resolved a little too early. I am sorry! The code works when I have just one question. When I have more than one, clicking on + reveals the answers for all other questions. That is why I was wanting to copy the toggle function you see in http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/truehost/js/custom.js However copying that code in my .js did not work :(  http://jsfiddle.net/u2ec3ce2/9/

Comment: @BhavaniKannan can you update the fiddle to reflect this with multiple questions?

Comment: @BhavaniKannan updated my answer, but do you want the other ones to hide when you toggle the new one open?

Comment: Nope. I do not want the other ones to close. Using siblings did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need any of that CSS. You can achieve this easily with jQuery only.

```
<div class="toggle-item">
    <div class="toggle-header">
        Question text
    <div>
    <div class="toggle-content" style="display:none;">
        /* Answer here */
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in jquery:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.toggle-header', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
    $target.siblings('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's beneficial you took their css for aesthetics but it doesn't do much for the animation.

Here's a js fiddle with working slide up/down

http://jsfiddle.net/44v8yggp/

Essentially you use jquery animate with `height:'toggle',opacity:'toggle'`